# line numbers in Arabic poem

Tags: footnotes, line-numbering, arabic

I am typing an Arabic poem as part of a longer `XeLaTeX` document.  So my paper has three parts:  Introduction (7 pages), edition of Arabic poem (5 pages) that I typeset using `polyglossia` and `bidi` `\traditional poem` (two justified columns), and translation of the Arabic poem (4 pages). I need to add some footnotes (textual variants) in the Arabic poem.  I want to have the footnote marker in Arabic (`mashriq`) but when I insert at the beginning of the Arabic poem the command `\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}` it changes both footnote markers and page numbers to `mashriq` (including also the page numbers in the translation section.  (If I insert the command in the preamble, it changes all numerals in the document to `mashriq` form.)

I would ideally like the footnotes to be on the bottom of each page, but the `traditionalpoem` environment seems to insert them only at the end of the poem.  I can live with that.

1. Is there some way to get `mashriq` forms only in the footnote markers within the Arabic text section without changing any other numbers to `mashriq` form?
2. Another, presumably easier, solution would be to number the lines of
   the text of the Arabic poem and create unnumbered footnotes that
   reference line numbers rather than  specific footnote markers, but I
   have not found a way to accomplish this.  I tried using package
   `lineno`.  It did not produce any error messages but it also did not
   number the lines of the poem.  I have found examples of code
   defining a new environment, `numberedpoem`, published on the internet
   which apparently work for some people, but when I run the example
   through `TeXWorks` (`MikTeX 2.9`) it does not compile.  There is an
   error code:

   ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.63 \footdir@temp
                 \footdir@ORG@xepersian@footnotetext\@footnotetext{\bidi@fo...
   ```

I am at a loss to know what to do because the sample does not even contain 63 lines of code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a small complete compilable document that shows the problem.  It doesn't need to have the whole poem, but just enough to show the issue.